# How much weight does pasta gain when boiled?

Tags: pasta, dietary-restriction

In the diet my dietetician has prescribed me, I have amount of pasta allowed listed for dry (uncooked) pasta.

This is not a problem if I have the foresight to weigh the pasta before boiling, but it is a problem if I buy a dish with ready-made pasta or forget to weigh it before cooking (or just forget how much I had measured, and didn't write down).

Can you give me a rule of thumb / estimate, how much 75g of dry pasta weighs after it's boiled?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but the answer contains the ratio which I seek, in the calculations to obtain the amount of water absorbed alone (minus pasta): **So 100g dry pasta turns into 100g*75/31 = 242g of cooked pasta**. My 75g would convert to 187g of cooked pasta.

Comment: @SF. You can answer your own questions! I would recommend converting your comment into an answer in this case. If it doesn't get closed as a duplicate you'll get the appropriate votes for working out the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accepted answer to the [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42484/how-much-water-does-pasta-absorb-when-it-is-cooked) about a closely related matter: "*how much water does pasta absorb*", to obtain its result goes through a calculation involving direct answer to my question.

> 100g dry pasta turns into 100g*75/31 = 242g of cooked pasta.

and

> The estimate below from the nutrition facts is 1.4x, which probably corresponds to typical American overcooked pasta - a surprisingly large difference from mine. I'm guessing you'll be somewhere between, maybe 1.25x.

Obviously getting the amount of pasta+water involves simply increasing these factors by 1, so **al dente will weigh 2.25x the original**, and **'typical American overcooked pasta' will be 2.4x the original weight**.

For my allowance of 75g that gives me 180g of "overcooked" pasta or 170g of al dente.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. I'm attempting to find out how much my baby weighs in angel hair pasta. For a friend that is....right.